# Sorting by value Hash of Hashes Perl

Tags: perl, sorting, hash-of-hashes

Let's say I have a hash of hashes data structure constructed as followed:

```
%HoH => (
     flintstones => {
               family_members    => "fred;wilma;pebbles;dino",
               number_of_members => 4,
     },
     jetsons => {
               family_members    => "george;jane;elroy",
               number_of_members => 3,
     },
     simpsons => {
               family_members    => "homer;marge;bart;lisa;maggie",
               number_of_members => 5,
     },

)
```

How do I sort the keys, the families in this case, by the value `number_of_members` from greatest to least? Then I would like to print out the highest two. Here's a general idea but I know it's wrong:

```
foreach $value (
    sort {
    $HoH{$a}{$number_of_members} cmp $HoH{$b}{$number_of_members}
    } keys %HoH)
my $count = 0;
while ($key, $value) = each %HoH) {
    if (count <= 2){
        print "${HoH}{$key}\t$key{$value}";
    }
}
continue {
    $count++;
};
```

I want the code to print (the spaces are tab delimited):

```
simpsons    homer;marge;bart;lisa;maggie
flintstones    fred;wilma;pebbles;dino
```

Comment: Replace cmp with <=>. Your doing a numercal comparison

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're on the right track. You use the `$a` and `$b` internal variables in the hash and compare the values numerically (`<=>` not `cmp`).

When printing, I find it easiest to store the keys in an array and use an array slice to access them.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %HoH = (
     flintstones => {
               family_members    => "fred;wilma;pebbles;dino",
               number_of_members => 4,
     },
     jetsons => {
               family_members    => "george;jane;elroy",
               number_of_members => 3,
     },
     simpsons => {
               family_members    => "homer;marge;bart;lisa;maggie",
               number_of_members => 5,
     },    
);
my @sorted = sort { $HoH{$b}{'number_of_members'} <=> 
                    $HoH{$a}{'number_of_members'} } keys %HoH;

for (@sorted[0,1]) {   # print only first two
    print join("\t", $_, $HoH{$_}{'family_members'}), "\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
simpsons        homer;marge;bart;lisa;maggie
flintstones     fred;wilma;pebbles;dino
```

Comment: thank you. I have to look over it a bit more to make sense of everything but I understand the gist of it.

Comment: @cooldood3490 You're welcome. Feel free to ask if there's something that is not clear.